# Save Email attachments to Google drive Attachment name deletes the letter automatically

Tags: power-automate

I have created the flow to save my outlook attachment to save it google drive as a separate folder when ever I receive email with attachment.

But the problem is on the below highlighted screenshot when I type really slowly to the core `Attachments From` in the folder path it works but if I do the normal typing it keeps on deleting the letter. Any idea how to fix this behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is you probably have selected some destination folder from drop-down menu and that is why such a miracle happens. And I guess it is not a bug but a feature.

How to overcome that? Just type/paste your desired value or add a `dynamic content` (or both).

[image]

Comment: Great! I will raise a uservoice for this